# Is there an intuitive notation for a vector of sums by group?

Tags: notation, vectors

Given two vectors (exampled below as a matrix) X and Y, what is the proper notation for an equation that results in a vector of the sums (or averages) of vector Y by vector X?

An example of what I was thinking is below but perhaps there is something much clearer.

$$\begin{bmatrix}*X* & *Y*\\a & 1\\a & 2\\b & 3\\b & 4\\c & 5\end{bmatrix}  \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^NY_i \Big[ X = \{a,b,c\}\Big] = \begin{bmatrix}a & 3\\b & 7\\c & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}*X* & *Y*\\a & 1\\a & 2\\b & 3\\b & 4\\c & 5\end{bmatrix}  \rightarrow \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NY_i \Big[ X = \{a,b,c\}\Big] = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1.5\\b & 3.5\\c & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

Where the result is not actually a matrix, but the Y Vector.

**EDIT:** for more context.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y & z\\ \hline
a & 1 & 3\\
a & 2 & 3\\
b & 3 & 7\\
b & 4 & 7\\
c & 5 & 5\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}$$

I'm basically trying to come up with a quick way of expressing the question/statement: for each unique element in vector x, does the sum of y (let's call it $M$) equal the average of z (which we're calling $V$).

This is so that I can denote a minimization function in optimization, $minimize\ V-M\ subject\ to\ M\leqq V$.

Comment: Your notation is very confusing. Of course, you’re asking about better notation, so this makes sense! Could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: I suppose I should not have made matrices when i was only talking about vectors. It’s the middle equation that i’m interested in. How can I denote summing by a group

Comment: Your use of matrices is fine—vectors are very commonly describe with matrices, and in the general sense, matrices are in fact vectors (you can read about that by searching up “vector spaces”). I don’t know what you mean by “summing by a group.” Could you very explicitly describe what you are looking for in an addendum to your question? Context about why you’re looking for this would also help solve your problem.

Comment: Never mind! I think I just figured it out…

Comment: Summing by a group, as in summing elements of one vector by unique elements of another vector? I guess it’s not necessarily numeric elements as I’m showing above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more context, I would be happy to provide a more specialized answer. But for now, I think this should be fine. It’s less than succinct, but it’s also very general.

---

Say you have these data:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y \\ \hline
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
b & 3 \\
b & 4 \\
c & 5 \\
\end{array}$$

This set of data is equivalent to $$\Bbb{U} = \bigl\{ (a,1) , (a,2) , (b,3) , (b,4) , (c,5) \bigr\}$$

Define

$$\begin{align}
A &= \bigl\{ y : (a,y) \in \Bbb{U} \bigr\} \\
B &= \bigl\{ y : (b,y) \in \Bbb{U} \bigr\} \\
C &= \bigl\{ y : (c,y) \in \Bbb{U} \bigr\} \\
\end{align}$$

From these parameter you can develop the mapping

$$M(\Bbb{U}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \displaystyle \sum_{y\in A}y \\
b & \displaystyle \sum_{y\in B}y \\
c & \displaystyle \sum_{y\in C}y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And for your averages, you can take

$$V(\Bbb{U}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \displaystyle \frac{1}{\lvert A \rvert} \sum_{y\in A}y \\
b & \displaystyle \frac{1}{\lvert B \rvert} \sum_{y\in B}y \\
c & \displaystyle \frac{1}{\lvert C \rvert} \sum_{y\in C}y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\lvert A \rvert$ is the cardinality of $A$ (the number of elements it has).

---

If you wanted to extend the argument to a general number of rows, to limit it, or to leave it generally open-ended, you could define for yourself some $M(\Bbb{U}; a, b, \cdots, x)$.

Upon reading your last comment, I’d like to point out that the $y$-data don’t have to be numbers; they just have to be anything that can be added to one another.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I added some context and am wondering if that changes anything. It seems lengthy to define each and every element of the group vector, i'm wondering if there is something more general? I'm a mathematics noob and had to google the $U$.

Comment: @EvanFriedland $\Bbb U$ is just the symbol I decided to use. Symbols themselves have no meaning. It’s all in how the author defines them.